# PRIORITY_LOW_POWER vs PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY for google play service v2

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm wondering for the fused location, does any of the above use a combination of gps + wifi network together? what is the difference in terms of provider (does any of it uses the gps)? from what i see in the documentation the difference is only distance

I've previously worked with LocationManager and used NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER together to get a combination of those two provider.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The new fused location providers take a slightly different approach compared to previous methods. Developers now choose how much battery power is used to calculate a location instead of which device components are used to calculate it. It uses any available combination of GPS, Wi-Fi, mobile networks, and onboard sensors to calculate the location.

The `LocationRequest` priority settings are now:

- `PRIORITY_NO_POWER` (passively listens for location updates from other clients)
- `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` (~10km "city" accuracy)
- `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` (~100m "block" accuracy)
- `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` (accurate as possible at the expense of battery life)

Google describes the `LocationRequest` class here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

Comment: More information about location priorities in Google documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery#accuracy