# What is the difference between LocationRequest priorities for Android's Fused Location Provider?

Tags: android, android-location

I'm writing an application where battery consumption and location accuracy are critical. I've spent some time researching the differences between the available priorities in the Fused Location Provider available in Google Play Services, but I have not been able to find concrete data on what each setting does exactly.

The [LocationRequest API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html) provides a brief overview of the expected accuracy and power usage. [This website](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider) references a [Google IO presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URcVZybzMUI) which mentions the data sources and an example of battery drain differences between priorities. I am look for more specific information.

Will Balanced never initialize the GPS, on any device, in any situation? Does High Accuracy always use GPS? What is the difference between Balanced and Low Power? If the device has both WiFi and cell network disabled, will Balanced or Low Power ever return a Location?

I have performed tests on multiple devices and compared results between different priorities and Location Providers and discovered some information, but I have no idea how consistent my results will be across phones. I'd like to see more information from Google. I have been unable to find any official information aside from the sources above.

Is there more official information on the differences between LocationRequest priorities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PRIORITY\_LOW\_POWER vs PRIORITY\_BALANCED\_POWER\_ACCURACY for google play service v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768048/priority-low-power-vs-priority-balanced-power-accuracy-for-google-play-service-v)

Comment: can someone from Android answer this?

Comment: Please refer this Link. This may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200690/fused-location-provider-unexpected-behavior

Answer (score 1):

1]PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY: Used with setPriority(int) to request "block" level accuracy.

2]PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY:   Used with setPriority(int) to request the most accurate locations available.

3]PRIORITY_LOW_POWER:   Used with setPriority(int) to request "city" level accuracy.

4]PRIORITY_NO_POWER:    Used with setPriority(int) to request the best accuracy possible with zero additional power consumption.

for details:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest