# Failing to retrieve Location with 4G

Tags: android, gps, 4g

I'm trying to retrieve Location with

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

When I am connected to Wifi, there is no problem, but when I disconnect Wifi and let 4G determine location, I get no gps fix...

The thing is I receive Internet through 4G, so I don't understand why!

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is the Google Location Services, AKA "Network" location, relies heavily on Wi-Fi networks to determine location.

Getting a location from the cellular network can be flaky, especially depending on where you are.  If you are in the downtown area of a city, there are lots of cell towers around, so triangulation can better determine your location than if you're in a less dense area.

It's not really explicitly stated in the documentation, but it looks like using `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` probably uses "passive" use of the GPS radio, meaning that it will only give you data from the GPS radio if another app requested a location callback, so you basically piggy-back onto that request, and your app doesn't get blamed for any battery drain even though you get the location data.

The documentation states:

> In between these two extremes is a very common use-case, where
>   applications definitely want to receive updates at a specified
>   interval, and can receive them faster when available, but still want a
>   low power impact. These applications should consider
>   PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY combined with a faster
>   setFastestInterval(long) (such as 1 minute) and a slower
>   setInterval(long) (such as 60 minutes). They will only be assigned
>   power blame for the interval set by setInterval(long), but can still
>   receive locations triggered by other applications at a rate up to
>   setFastestInterval(long). This style of request is appropriate for
>   many location aware applications, including background usage. Do be
>   careful to also throttle setFastestInterval(long) if you perform
>   heavy-weight work after receiving an update - such as using the
>   network.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long)

See this post as well: [PRIORITY_LOW_POWER vs PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY for google play service v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768048/priority-low-power-vs-priority-balanced-power-accuracy-for-google-play-service-v/21101175#21101175)